# How can I get all the card in the array to show?

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

The output is weird. This is for a class and I need to alter the toString method somehow to make this work, but I don't know how. This gives me what I think are memory locations like Card@wods903je0d and so on. I created an array with all possible cards, but I don't know how to display them. I need help please.

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
// wblab17.java
// This is the Student starting version for the <Deck> class lab assignment. 


public class wblab17100
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      System.out.println("Lab11bst.JAVA");
      System.out.println();     
      Deck deck = new Deck();
      System.out.println(deck);
   }
}

class Card {
   private String suit; 
   private String rank; 
   private int pointValue;
   public Card(String s, String r, int pV) {
      suit = s;
      rank = r; 
      pointValue = pV;
   }
}


class Deck 
{
   private Card[] cards;
   private int size;

   public Deck() 
   {
  size = 52;
  cards = new Card[size];
  Card n1 = new Card("Clubs", "Two", 2);
  Card n2 = new Card("Clubs", "Three", 3);
  Card n3 = new Card("Clubs", "Four", 4);
  Card n4 = new Card("Clubs", "Five", 5);
  Card n5 = new Card("Clubs", "Six", 6);
  Card n6 = new Card("Clubs", "Seven", 7);
  Card n7 = new Card("Clubs", "Eight", 8);
  Card n8 = new Card("Clubs", "Nine", 9);
  Card n9 = new Card("Clubs", "Ten", 10);
  Card n10 = new Card("Clubs", "Jack", 10);
  Card n11 = new Card("Clubs", "Queen", 10);
  Card n12 = new Card("Clubs", "King", 10);
  Card n13 = new Card("Clubs", "Ace", 11);
  Card n14 = new Card("Diamonds", "Two", 2);
  Card n15 = new Card("Diamonds", "Three", 3);
  Card n16 = new Card("Diamonds", "Four", 4);
  Card n17 = new Card("Diamonds", "Five", 5);
  Card n18 = new Card("Diamonds", "Six", 6);
  Card n19 = new Card("Diamonds", "Seven", 7);
  Card n20 = new Card("Diamonds", "Eight", 8);
  Card n21 = new Card("Diamonds", "Nine", 9);
  Card n22 = new Card("Diamonds", "Ten", 10);
  Card n23 = new Card("Diamonds", "Jack", 10);
  Card n24 = new Card("Diamonds", "Queen", 10);
  Card n25 = new Card("Diamonds", "King", 10);
  Card n26 = new Card("Diamonds", "Ace", 11);
  Card n27 = new Card("Hearts", "Two", 2);
  Card n28 = new Card("Hearts", "Three", 3);
  Card n29 = new Card("Hearts", "Four", 4);
  Card n30 = new Card("Hearts", "Five", 5);
  Card n31 = new Card("Hearts", "Six", 6);
  Card n32 = new Card("Hearts", "Seven", 7);
  Card n33 = new Card("Hearts", "Eight", 8);
  Card n34 = new Card("Hearts", "Nine", 9);
  Card n35 = new Card("Hearts", "Ten", 10);
  Card n36 = new Card("Hearts", "Jack", 10);
  Card n37 = new Card("Hearts", "Queen", 10);
  Card n38 = new Card("Hearts", "King", 10);
  Card n39 = new Card("Hearts", "Ace", 11);
  Card n40 = new Card("Spades", "Two", 2);
  Card n41 = new Card("Spades", "Three", 3);
  Card n42 = new Card("Spades", "Four", 4);
  Card n43 = new Card("Spades", "Five", 5);
  Card n44 = new Card("Spades", "Six", 6);
  Card n45 = new Card("Spades", "Seven", 7);
  Card n46 = new Card("Spades", "Eight", 8);
  Card n47 = new Card("Spades", "Nine", 9);
  Card n48 = new Card("Spades", "Ten", 10);
  Card n49 = new Card("Spades", "Jack", 10);
  Card n50 = new Card("Spades", "Queen", 10);
  Card n51 = new Card("Spades", "King", 10);
  Card n52 = new Card("Spades", "Ace", 11);

  cards[0]= n1;
  cards[1]= n2;
  cards[2]= n3;
  cards[3]= n4;
  cards[4]= n5;
  cards[5]= n6;
  cards[6]= n7;
  cards[7]= n8;
  cards[8]= n9;
  cards[9]= n10;
  cards[10]= n11;
  cards[11]= n12;
  cards[12]= n13;
  cards[13]= n14;
  cards[14]= n15;
  cards[15]= n16;
  cards[16]= n17;
  cards[17]= n18;
  cards[18]= n19;
  cards[19]= n20;
  cards[20]= n21;
  cards[21]= n22;
  cards[22]= n23;
  cards[23]= n24;
  cards[24]= n25;
  cards[25]= n26;
  cards[26]= n27;
  cards[27]= n28;
  cards[28]= n29;
  cards[29]= n30;
  cards[30]= n31;
  cards[31]= n32;
  cards[32]= n33;
  cards[33]= n34;
  cards[34]= n35;
  cards[35]= n36;
  cards[36]= n37;
  cards[37]= n38;
  cards[38]= n39;
  cards[39]= n40;
  cards[40]= n41;
  cards[41]= n42;
  cards[42]= n43;
  cards[43]= n44;
  cards[44]= n45;
  cards[45]= n46;
  cards[46]= n47;
  cards[47]= n48;
  cards[48]= n49;
  cards[49]= n50;
  cards[50]= n51;
  cards[51]= n52;
   }

   public String toString(){
      String arr = "";
      for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
         arr = arr + cards[i].toString() +"\n";
      }
      return arr;
   }    
 }
```

Comment: `Card` needs to override `toString` so you can pass back the details you want.  Personally, not my favourite thing to do as I prefer `toString` to be for diagnostic/debug information.  Perhaps in your `toString` of `Desk` you should make user of the properties in `Card` to format the result the way you want

Answer (score 1):

Issue with your code is that you are overridding toString() method in Deck class while you should override in Card class. As you have not overridden toString() method for Card class, implementation provided in Object class is getting executed which prints memory location of the given object. If you want to print the field values of objects then override the toString() method in Card class as per your print logic. Below is one of the way overriding toString method for your Card class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Card{" +
            "suit= '" + suit + '\'' +
            ", rank= '" + rank + '\'' +
            ", pointValue=" + pointValue +
            '}';
}
```

Comment: What's the point of answering the same stuff again? And If I am not wrong, you copied the code snippet from my answer!!

Comment: I guided him with the problem in his code and explained to him how things work instead of just providing an implementation of toString() method and not telling him what is wrong and how to take care of the same in future.

Comment: That is already explained in the comment by @MadProgrammer! Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Provide `toString()` method in `Card` class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Card{" +
            "suit='" + suit + '\'' +
            ", rank='" + rank + '\'' +
            ", pointValue=" + pointValue +
            '}';
}
```